# Memory corruption by strtok_r

Tags: c, strtok

I am trying to do a nested `strtok_r`. I have a `gzippped csv` file which i am trying to read using `zpipe.c`. I notice that when i try to print out `out` variable it adds some weird characters to it if i use strtok_r second time. All works fine till i uncomment the second strtok_r line. Then i start seeing garbage values at the end of printf(out) statement. What befuddles me even more is that i print out `out` variable way before anything to do with second `strtok_r`. How does it manage to get corrupted because of something which hasn't yet happened is very confusing.

```
#include "system.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "zlib.h"

struct timeval begTime;
#if defined(MSDOS) || defined(OS2) || defined(WIN32) || 
defined(__CYGWIN__)
#  include <fcntl.h>
#  include <io.h>
#  define SET_BINARY_MODE(file) setmode(fileno(file), O_BINARY)
#else
#  define SET_BINARY_MODE(file)
#endif

#define CHUNK 16384

int inf(FILE *source, FILE *dest)
{
    int ret;
    unsigned have;
    z_stream strm;
    unsigned char in[CHUNK];
    unsigned char out[CHUNK];

    /* allocate inflate state */
    strm.zalloc = Z_NULL;
    strm.zfree = Z_NULL;
    strm.opaque = Z_NULL;
    strm.avail_in = 0;
    strm.next_in = Z_NULL;
    ret = inflateInit2(&strm, 15|32);
    if (ret != Z_OK)
            return ret;

    do {
            memset(in, 0, CHUNK);
            strm.avail_in = fread(in, 1, CHUNK, source);
            printf("read %d\n", strm.avail_in);
            if (ferror(source)) {
                    (void)inflateEnd(&strm);
                    return Z_ERRNO;
            }
            if (strm.avail_in == 0)
                    break;
            strm.next_in = in;

            do {
                    strm.avail_out = CHUNK;
                    strm.next_out = out;
                    ret = inflate(&strm, Z_NO_FLUSH);
                    assert(ret != Z_STREAM_ERROR);  /* state not clobbered */
                    switch (ret) {
                            case Z_NEED_DICT:


do {
                    strm.avail_out = CHUNK;
                    strm.next_out = out;
                    ret = inflate(&strm, Z_NO_FLUSH);
                    assert(ret != Z_STREAM_ERROR);  /* state not clobbered */
                    switch (ret) {
                            case Z_NEED_DICT:
                                    ret = Z_DATA_ERROR;     /* and fall through */
                            case Z_DATA_ERROR:
                            case Z_MEM_ERROR:
                                    (void)inflateEnd(&strm);
                                    return ret;
                    }
                    have = CHUNK - strm.avail_out;
                    printf("out, %s\n", out);
                    char *cylv_line;
                    char *savePtr = (char*)out;
                    cylv_line = strtok_r(savePtr, "\n", &savePtr); // size of buffer always be greater than used
                    int line_num =0;
                    printf("before contract cm\n");
                    gettimeofday(&begTime, NULL);
                    int sumlen = 0;
                    while(cylv_line != NULL)
                    {
                            //all works fine till i uncomment this line. Then i start seeing garbage values at the end of printf(out) statement 
                            //cylv_line = strtok_r(savePtr, "\n", &savePtr);
                            line_num++;
                    }
                    printf("odone, %s\n", out);
                    if (ferror(dest)) {
                            (void)inflateEnd(&strm);
                            return Z_ERRNO;
                    }
            } while (strm.avail_out == 0);
            /* done when inflate() says it's done */
    } while (ret != Z_STREAM_END);

(void)inflateEnd(&strm);
    return ret == Z_STREAM_END ? Z_OK : Z_DATA_ERROR;
}

void zerr(int ret)
{
    fputs("zpipe: ", stderr);
    switch (ret) {
            case Z_ERRNO:
                    if (ferror(stdin))
                            fputs("error reading stdin\n", stderr);
                    if (ferror(stdout))
                            fputs("error writing stdout\n", stderr);
                    break;
            case Z_STREAM_ERROR:
                    fputs("invalid compression level\n", stderr);
                    break;
            case Z_DATA_ERROR:
                    fputs("invalid or incomplete deflate data\n", stderr);
                    break;
            case Z_MEM_ERROR:
                    fputs("out of memory\n", stderr);
                    break;
            case Z_VERSION_ERROR:
                    fputs("zlib version mismatch!\n", stderr);
    }
  }

 int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
    int ret;
    ret = inf(fopen(argv[1],"r"), stdout);
    if (ret != Z_OK)
            zerr(ret);
    return ret;

}
```

I have put in bold the garbage that is added when i run the nested strtok_r

39,1489116595360920,1,19,39,N,1173603600662,1000000000000369,1225,B,75000,2000
40,1489116595360937,1,19,40,N,1173603600662,1000000000000370,1223,B,75000,2000
41,1489116595360952,1,19,41,N,1173603600662,1000000000000371,1269,B,665050000,10
42,1489116595360964,1,19,42,N,1173603600662,1000000000000372,1269,B,665225000,100
43,1489116595360977,1,19,43,N,1173603600662,1000000000000373,1269,S,670475000,10
44,1489116595361024,1,19,44,N,1173603600662,1000000000000374,1269,S,669950000,10
45,1489116595361072,1,19,45,N,1173603600662,1000000000000375,1237,B,75000,2000
46,1489116595361078,1,19,46,N,1173603600662,1000000000000376,1269,B,667250000,10
47,1489116595361082,1,19,47,N,1173603600662,1000000000000377,1269,B,667525000,5
48,1489116595361085,1,19,48,N,1173603600662,1000000000000378,1327,B,75000,2000
49,1489116595361087,1,19,49,N,1173603600662,1000000000000379,1279,B,100000,2500
50,1489116595361095,1,19,50,N,1173603600662,1000000000000380,1269,B,665225000,200
51,1489116595361110,1,19,51,N,11736036006**ÑgÂ"ü^?**
before contract cm
odone, 1,1489116595360464,1,19,1,N,1173603600658,1000000000000333,1269,B,667125000,99
out, 62,1000000000000381,1008,B,25000,1373
52,1489116595361125,1,19,52,N,1173603600662,1000000000000382,1269,B,663225000,200
53,1489116595361139,1,19,53,N,1173603600662,1000000000000383,1387,S,150000,2000

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the [`strtok_r`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok_r.html) function wrong. In the subsequent calls the first argument should be the result of the *last* call (in your case `cylv_line`) and not the saved state.

So you should do e.g.

```
cylv_line = strtok_r(out, "\n", &savePtr);  // Initial call
...
while (cylv_line != NULL)
{
    ...
    cylv_line = strtok_r(cylv_line, "\n", &savePtr);
    ...
}
```

---

The *actual* problem is that you treat the expanded data as strings, but you don't add a string terminator.

Change the definition of `out` to have space for the terminator:

```
char out[CHUNK + 1];  // +1 for the string terminator
```

Then after inflation you add the terminator:

```
out[have] = '\0';  // Terminate as a C string
```

Without the terminator string functions (like `strtok` and `strtok_r`) will go beyond the end of the data and you will have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: That doesn't seem right. It stops after the first call.

Comment: @NaveenSharma And what is the contents of `out`? Are you sure you have multiple newlines in the string?

Comment: Yes, I have edited code to complete it. Though it is almost exactly same as zpipe.c other than what i added before.

Comment: The file does have multiple new lines. The problem happens when we run out of the buffer space.

Comment: @NaveenSharma Then the problem is probably something unrelated to `strtok_r`. Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger? And can you please edit your question to show what input (if any) you give, and the actual and expected output?

Comment: The expected output is just the same but without the garbage values in bold appended.

Comment: @NaveenSharma The *real* problem is simply a missing string terminator. Updated my answer

Comment: That did it. I had looked into that earlier but messed up the execution it seems, thanks!